# How to start with AJAX/JSON in Zend?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am working on some projects as a developer(PHP,MySQL) in which AJAX and jQuery is already implemented. But now I want to learn implementation of AJAX and jQuery stuff. Can anyone tell me the exact steps with explanation?

I have created a project in Zend. There is only one controller(IndexController) and two actions(a and b) in my project now. Now I want to use ajax in my project. But I don't know how to start. I read some tutorial but unable to completely understand.

I have index.phtml like this:

```
<a href='index/a'>Load info A</a>
<br/>
<a href='index/b'>Load info B</a>

<br />
<div id=one>load first here<div>
<div id=two>load second here</div>
```

Here index is controller in links.
a and b are actions.

now I have four files like this:

a1.phtml

```
I am a1
```

a2.phtml

```
I am a2
```

b1.phtml

```
I am b1
```

b2.phtml

```
I am b2
```

I think you have got my point.

When user clicks first link **(Load info A)** then **a1.phtml** should be loaded into **div one** and **a2.phtml** should be loaded into **div two**

When user clicks second link **(Load info B)** then **b1.phtml** should be loaded into **div one** and **b2.phtml** should be loaded into **div two**

Will someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about Zend(-controllers) but if you just want to load a1/a2/b1/b2.phtml I think this will help:

Put the following code in the  section of the page.
It will need the jQuery library to be included.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

The version doesn't have to be 1.4.2 but I've tested the code with that.

I've put explanation in the comments.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // This function will be executed when the page is loaded
    jQuery('#linkA').click(loadInfoA); // Here a 'click' event is registered on the links
    jQuery('#linkB').click(loadInfoB); // When the user clicks on of the link the functions (loadInfoA, loadInfoB) will be executed
});

function loadInfoA(event){ // This function will load the info from a1.phtml and a2.phtml
    event.preventDefault(); // This is to prevent the link (index/a) from being followed
                            // Otherwise the user would be leaving the page and a1/a2.phtml wouldn't
                            // be loaded into the divs
    jQuery.ajax({ // This is the main AJAX magic read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
        url: 'a1.phtml', // this is the page that will be loaded: a1.phtml
        success: function(data){ // this function will be executed when the data is loaded from the server
            jQuery('#one').html(data); // This will take div-one and put the from a1.phtml data in it
        }
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'a2.phtml', // a2.phtml will be loaded
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#two').html(data); // This will take div-two and put the data from a2.phtml in it
        }
    });
}
function loadInfoB(event){ // This function does the same as loadInfoA except that it will load b1/b2.phtml
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'b1.phtml',
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#one').html(data);
        }
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'b2.phtml',
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#two').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I've edited your HTML slightly so that jQuery can register a click event on the links

```
<a href='index/a' id="linkA">Load info A</a>
<br/>
<a href='index/b' id="linkB">Load info B</a>
<br />

<div id="one">load first here</div>
<div id="two">load second here</div>
```

PS: This is my first contribution on Stack Overflow. Please let me know if it was helpful, or what could be improved

Comment: You have to made js function for each link using your above logic. In fact, in zend, we use one class(for example: AJAX) for each link to load in AJAX. Then there is a .phtml file for each action, in which we describe that which file should be loaded in which div. It makes easy to control your code. Therefore I prefer a framework :) Anyway your answer is helpful for me to understand basic knowledge about AJAX. Thanks and Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a few lines in jQuery

```
$(function() { 

    wrapper_id = "ajax-wrapper";
    $('.tabdiv').wrap("<div id='"+ wrapper_id + "' />");
    $.historyInit(pageload);

    $('.tabNav li a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".tabNav li").removeClass("ui-tabs-selected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("ui-tabs-selected");
        $.historyLoad(href);
    });

});

function pageload(href) {
    if(href) {            
        $("#" + wrapper_id).load(href + " .tabdiv",'',function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $("#" + wrapper_id).fadeIn("");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in Zend I have a Layout Plugin that check for AJAX using XMLHttpRequest

```
$ajax = isset ( $_SERVER ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ? $_SERVER ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] : '';

if ($ajax == "XMLHttpRequest" || $request->getParam('ajax')) {
 return true;
}

echo Zend_Json::encode(array(
 'content'=>$data[$this->_defaultContentArea],
 'container'=>$request->container, 
));
```

Hope this helps